# How do I recover from Firefox safe mode overwritting my preferences?

Tags: firefox

My computer has a hardware fault and crashes frequently (but not often enough for me to replace it). Firefox did not like the crashes and offered me to start in safe mode. Somehow, even after restart, all my settings got deleted. I have no idea if and how can I recover my old settings and extesions.

Comment: You may also want to try renaming or deleting the crash profiles before starting firefox.

Comment: Hm, that could work, but I find it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a folder "Old Fireforx Data" on my desktop that I missed when I asked the question. I moved the folder inside it (called "hb0i6k54.default") into ~/.mozilla/firefox and edited profiles.ini in that folder so that it would point to hb0i6k54.default - and that fixed the problem.